# what is the "slowIndicatorLoggingThreshold" property in ReactiveHealthEndpointWebExtension - Spring Boot Health Indicator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

after upgrading to Spring Boot 3.
there is a new variable introduced in ReactiveHealthEndpointWebExtension. i,e. slowIndicatorLoggingThreshold

what is the usage and behaviour slowIndicatorLoggingThreshold?